# Can't Manage to move my player on unity, I'm using a tilebased movemen't

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm following this tutorial to create a tile-based movement for my player, but I can't understand why it isn't working. This is my code, but It doesn't work anyway.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    private bool isMoving;

    private Vector2 input;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            input.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            input.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

            if(input != Vector2.zero)
            {
                var targetPos = transform.position;
                targetPos.x += input.x;
                targetPos.y += input.y;

                StartCoroutine(Move(targetPos));
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        isMoving = true;

        while ((targetPos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                yield return null;
        }
        transform.position = targetPos;
        isMoving = false;
        }

    }
```

I tried changing the GetAxisRaw  for GetAxis only. Then I thought there was some kind of issue with my Keyboard and downloaded Unity Playground, but Everything works well with their scripts... I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your error is actually easy to fix. Just replace isMoving with !isMoving
since it starts with false or it never starts coroutine in the first place
`CODE:

```
public float moveSpeed;
private bool isMoving;
private Vector2 input;
private void Update()
{
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In your code field "isMoving" always in "false" value and coroutine "Move" never starts.
Maybe for tutorials coroutine for moving can be used, but I would use code like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        targetPosition.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        targetPosition.y += Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but this is a tile-based movement like Pokémon? So I need a very specific solution

Comment: According to your code it is not entirely clear what features the game has. Anyway you need to check the variable isMoving. It is private and its value is not set in your code and is equal to false